# How to render and bind choiceFile manually in Django

Tags: django

Am new to Django am trying to implement a simple `select` tag, the values are rendered with no problem but the value is not bound to the form during submission and I keep getting the message that the value is required

**Form**

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    job_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=JOB_TYPES)
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="browser-default custom-select">
        {% for type in form.job_type %}
        {{ type }}
        {% endfor %}

    </select>
</div>
```

**VIEW**

```
def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        return render(request, 'upload/upload.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

I also tried to do `{{ form.job_type }}` and this one works fine but then I can't use the required `css`, But I want to freely change `css` and `style` in the HTML file without referring to the form field in `forms.py`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the subwidgets of the `Select` widget, and then render the `option.data.label`:

```
{% for option in form.job_type %}
    <select value="{{ option.data.value }}">{{ option.data.label }}</select>
{% endfor %}
```

But if you however only want to apply a certain class to the `Select` widget, I advice you to specify this in the `attrs`, like:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    job_type = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'browser-default custom-select'}),
        choices=JOB_TYPES
    )
```

Comment: it seems there a missing `"`, but still, the loop doesn't display anything

Comment: @Exorcismus: sorry, I forgot `.widget`. Nevertheless, as said, it might be better to fix it with `attrs=...` since then you do not have to render the `<select>` part yourself.

Comment: still not working, option values are not displayed, I will go for the easier `attr` solution, yet it would be nice to get the `optgroups ` to work

Comment: @Exorcismus: the edit should work (I've tested this locally)

Comment: Willem, I tried ` <select class="browser-default custom-select">
                    {% for option in form.job_type %}
                    <option value="{{ option.data.value }}">{{ option.data.label }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>` , but still, value is not bound and form is not valid

Comment: @Exorcismus: yes, you need to add a `name="{{ form.job_type.name }}"` to your `<select>` tag.